# Rotate display on startup

Tags: boot, cron

I try to rotate my display on startup. (Console, NOT X11)

I do not really care if this happens before the bootup-sequence or afterwards. As long as the display is rotated once the login-prompt appears I am happy.

I managed to rotate my display using the following snippet:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate_all
```

this works when entered in the shell. Now I tried to put that into the (root-)crontab. But it does not seem to have any effect at all.

The crontab-version looks like this:

```
@reboot echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate_all
```

Running on most current raspbian (debian 11)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to do this with systemd, which makes it easy to run a script at a specific moment during boot. In your case, you need to do it **after** the framebuffer initialization and **before** the first user logs in. Create a file `/etc/systemd/system/fbrotate.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to rotate the screen during boot.

[Service]
Type=Simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo 2 > /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate_all'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
After=getty.target
```

Test it with `sudo systemctl start fbrotate`, and if it works, enable it system-wide with `sudo systemctl enable fbrotate.service`.

Answer (score 1):

sudo to root is pointless in the root cronab.  It is run as the root user.

Try

`@reboot echo 2 > /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate_all`